# I want to store information of each individuals in a increasing manner in a .txt file, the result returns me a incomplete element error(C language)

Tags: c

I want to code a function that retrieves information from user's input and then store that information in a array of structs. The information are then placed in a .txt file. Currently, the compiler's debug returns me the following error:

```
fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp); [error]: array type has incomplete element type
```

I'm open to any suggestion because I'm a newcomer in this field myself.

```
struct student{
    int rollNo;
    char studentID[50], studentName[50]; 
    float asm1Grade[50], asm2Grade[50], total[50];
} st[50];
void add_student(){
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        st[i].rollNo = i;
    
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tAdd new record\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t-------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the student's full name: ");
    fgets(st[i].studentName,50,stdin);
    fp = fopen("Students.txt","a+");
            fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the student's ID: ");
    fgets(st[i].studentID,50,stdin);
    fp = fopen("Students.txt","a+");
            fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter student's assignment 1 grade: ");
    fgets(st[i].asm1Grade,50,stdin);
    fp = fopen("Students.txt","a+");
            fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter student's assignment 2 grade: ");
    fgets(st[i].asm2Grade,50,stdin);
    fp = fopen("Students.txt","a+");
            fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `fwrite(st + i, ...`

Comment: If you write a partial record 4 times to the file, you will get data that you probably view as corrupt.  Read the entire struct and write it once.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.

What the compiler is telling you, is that there is no type `struct st`.
That is correct:

```c
struct student{
    int rollNo;
    char studentID[50], studentName[50]; 
    float asm1Grade[50], asm2Grade[50], total[50];
} st[50];
```

This declares a data type `struct student` and a variable `st` that is an array of 50 elements of type `struct student`.

Your expression `sizeof (struct st[i])` would be `sizeof(struct student[i])` or simple `sizeof (st)`. But more likely it should be `sizeof (struct st)` to write one single element.

But fixing only this expression will still leave multiple issues open:

Then you open the same file multiple times but do not close them ever. That causes memory leaks and you might face a problem when you tryo to open another file later.

You also have a problem with the data you read. `asm1Grade` and `asm2Grade` are arrays of `float`. It does not make any sense to read them via `fgets`.
Reading only one value for an array also looks weird. I am not sure what you want to do here.

Besides these fatal issues, you have a logic problem as well:

```c
// Some lines skipped in between...
    fgets(st[i].studentName,50,stdin);
    fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    fgets(st[i].studentID,50,stdin);
    fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    fgets(st[i].asm1Grade,50,stdin);
    fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
    fgets(st[i].asm2Grade,50,stdin);
    fwrite(&st,sizeof(struct st[i]),1,fp);
```

You write a full structure to your file after reading each of the 4 strings.
That will write 3 structs to your file where some fields do not hold any useful value. They contain indetermined values and will look corrupt in the file.
Instead you should only write one struct after you collected all data.

A fixed version could look like this:

```c
struct student{
    int rollNo;
    char studentID[50], studentName[50]; 
    char asm1Grade[50], asm2Grade[50], total[50];
} st[50];

void add_student(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        st[i].rollNo = i;
    
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tAdd new record\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-------------------------\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the student's full name: ");
        fgets(st[i].studentName,50,stdin);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter the student's ID: ");
        fgets(st[i].studentID,50,stdin);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter student's assignment 1 grade: ");
        fgets(st[i].asm1Grade,50,stdin);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter student's assignment 2 grade: ");
        fgets(st[i].asm2Grade,50,stdin);

        FILE *fp = fopen("Students.txt","a+");
        fwrite(&st[i],sizeof(student),1,fp);
        fclose(fp)
    }
}
```

I leave it for you to handle `asm1Grade` and `asm2Grade` in a different way.